# Static props validation in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-props

When using props validation in Vue, it only shows errors during the runtime in the browser console.

But I want to get props validation to work during the static code analysis phase (linting).

For example, I have used the default Vue 2 project template:

`HelloWorld.vue` is the component that has `msg` prop and it's required:

```
<template>
  <h1>Message: {{ msg }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`App.vue` is using `HelloWorld` component, but doesn't specify `msg` prop. Instead, it uses non-existent prop `something`:

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld :something="somewhat" />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

I expect at least some of these requirements to be met when I run `npm run lint`:

- it should say `Error: required "msg" prop not found`
- it should say `Warning: unknown "something" prop has been used`
- also, if I assign something other than `String` to `msg` prop, it should say `Error: prop "msg" should be String, but received *NotString*`

In other words, I want Vue templates to be lintable, like JSX templates in React.

Is there any way I can achieve this in Vue 2 or Vue 3? Perhaps, some eslint plugins?

If this can be solved using TypeScript - that would be super awesome.

Comment: This would be amazing, but I don't think it exists :( 
Closest solution that I'm aware of is [Vue 3 + Typescript Prop annotation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-return-types)

Comment: Thanks, @Nazaire, I'm trying Vue 3 and Prop annotation, but no luck with triggering lint errors so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem, which works in both Vue 2 and Vue 3 is to use JSX (TSX).

Here's a Vue 3 example:

`HelloWorld.tsx`:

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup: (props) => () => <h1>{props.msg}</h1>,
});
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  render: () => <HelloWorld msg={"123"} />,
});
```

Here's Vue 2 example repo: https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/vue-2-tsx-example

And Vue 3: https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/vue-3-tsx-example